# Chrome opens last session despite all tabs being closed individually

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I have Chrome set to open to one tab only -- Google. However, after closing every tab and relaunching Chrome, all the previously-closed tabs are loaded instead. Not the last tab from the last session, but **all** of them. I've double- and triple-checked the settings, and they're as intended, but Chrome seems to simply ignore them. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Chrome settings and in "On startup" section you should select "Open the new tab page" or "Open a specific page or pages". If this doesn't work, sometimes you have to reinstall Chrome to have a fresh start.

Answer (score 0):

Click on "Show hidden icon arrow" Which is Present into the right-bottom of the taskbar and exit the chrome properly and restart the chrome. its works for me hope same will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

On a MAC = open chrome with a tab or two- then select apple menu and FORCE QUIT.

Find Chrome on the list and quit it

On restart it now closes all tabs when dismissed

Answer (score -1):

Open Chrome settings.  Open Advanced.  Scroll all the way down to System and turn off, "continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed."

Comment: Read over https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead to ensure you understand how you can start commenting.

Comment: This does not seem to answer the problem: Chrome is loading all previously closed tabs instead of opening one tab only.

Comment: Really?  What OS are you running, Vylix?  And when did the problem start?  I'm on Windows 10 and it showed up out of nowhere.  Like something must have updated and changed by itself.  Making this change cleared up my problem.

Comment: It worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

Go to chrome settings>Advanced>Reset. Reset the settings and it does the work.